# Foreach loop always add first character of string to the array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am making a function that can help me to cast the string to array, but that strange when the function always add first character to the array. Thank at first and this is code i used in function:

```
   $string = '0:009987;1:12312;2:45231;3:00985;3:10923;4:11253;4:62341;4:01102;4:58710;4:10102;4:87093;4:12034;5:9801;6:1092;6:4305;6:1090;7:450;8:34';
$explodedString = explode(';', $string);

//var_dump($explodedString);
$takeArray = array();
$counti = 0;
foreach($explodedString as $exploded){
 $secondExp = explode(':', $exploded);
 var_dump($secondExp);
 if(isset($takeArray[$secondExp[0]])){
  $takeArray[$secondExp[0]][$counti] = $secondExp[1];
 }else{
  $takeArray[$secondExp[0]] = $secondExp[1];
 }
 $counti++;
}

var_dump($takeArray);
```

This is current output of this code:

```
array (size=9)


0 => string '009987' (length=6)
  1 => string '12312' (length=5)
  2 => string '45231' (length=5)
  3 => string '00981' (length=5)
  4 => string '11253 605181' (length=12)
  5 => string '9801' (length=4)
  6 => string '1092          41' (length=16)
  7 => string '450' (length=3)
  8 => string '34' (length=2)
```

Looking into row 4 you will see the string: '605181', this string come from the first character of each value belong to 4. But i need an output array like this:

```
[0] => {'009987'},
....
[4] => { '11253', '62341', ...., },
....
```

Please help me.

Comment: Give an example output that you want, so I can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @monace19 updated what i am expecting. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `$counti`. All you need to do is, initialize the `$takeArray[$n]` if it doesn't exists, and push a new value to it. Something like this:

```
if(!isset($takeArray[$secondExp[0]])) {
    // Initialize the array
    $takeArray[$secondExp[0]] = array();
}

// Push the new value to the array
$takeArray[$secondExp[0]][] = $secondExp[1];
```

Comment: i need to add every element i have exploded to the array, not just only unique element. If it the key is exits on array i need to add another value to that key but not create the new one

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do the following :

```
$takeArray = array();
foreach($explodedString as $exploded) {
  $secondExp = explode(':', $exploded);
  $takeArray[(int)$secondExp[0]][] = $secondExp[1];
}
```

Comment: So the problem is we need to cast the string to int?

Comment: I did this because you seemed to want a classic array, indexed by integers.

But your manipulation with the $counti was kinda tricky ; you were incrementing it in a totally non-related for each loop, it could lead to errors.

Comment: i see the problem now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '0:009987;1:12312;2:45231;3:00985;3:10923;4:11253;4:62341;4:01102;4:58710;4:10102;4:87093;4:12034;5:9801;6:1092;6:4305;6:1090;7:450;8:34';
$explodedString = explode(';', $string);

$takeArray = array();
foreach($explodedString as $exploded)
{
    $secondExp = explode(':', $exploded);
    $takeArray[$secondExp[0]][] = $secondExp[1];
}

var_dump($takeArray);
```